# Chrome mobile position fixed bug

Tags: css, google-chrome, mobile, fixed

Container position fixed, whenever I scroll down or up on Chrome mobile works perfectly, but while you're scrolling and suddenly change scrolling direction the div will scroll a little (about 50 px) it will return to the fixed position when the scrolling stops.

Comment: What device(s) are you using?

Comment: HUAWEI P30 PRO.